# can anyone help me to optimize the where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

i have a below query it using index but not yet optimized I don't know what is the problem can anyone help me with this ?

```
select 
  date(mfd.MFD_FITMENT_DATE) as MFD_FITMENT_DATE, 
  count(*) cnt_fitment 
FROM 
  MMHSRP_FITMENT_DATE mfd, 
  CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_DETAILS crd, 
  EMBOSSING_STATION_MAPPING_DETAILS esmd 
where 
  mfd.MFD_CRD_ID = crd.CRD_ID 
  AND esmd.ESMD_SDM_ID = crd.CRD_SDM_ID 
  AND esmd.ESMD_ESM_ID = '9'
  AND mfd.MFD_STATUS = '0' 
  AND mfd.MFD_FITMENT_DATE >= '2022-10-07' 
  AND mfd.MFD_FITMENT_DATE <= '2022-12-06' 
  AND crd.CRD_VARIFICATION_STATUS IN (1, 2, 4) 
GROUP BY 
  mfd.MFD_FITMENT_DATE 
HAVING 
  COUNT(*) >= '5000' \G
```

```
    *************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: esmd
         type: ref
possible_keys: idx_ESMD_SDM_ID,idx_ESMD_ESM_ID
          key: idx_ESMD_ESM_ID
      key_len: 8
          ref: const
         rows: 440
        Extra: Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: crd
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_CRD_SDM_ID,idx_CRD_VARIFICATION_STATUS,idx_crd_sdm_id_verfication_status
          key: idx_crd_sdm_id_verfication_status
      key_len: 4
          ref: celexkeyline.esmd.ESMD_SDM_ID
         rows: 660
        Extra: Using where; Using index
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: mfd
         type: ref
possible_keys: MFD_STATUS,idx_MFD_CRD_ID,idx_combo,idx_new,MFD_FITMENT_DATE,idx_CRD_FIT_DATE_STATUS
          key: MFD_STATUS
      key_len: 12
          ref: const,celexkeyline.crd.CRD_ID
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index
```

row 3 Table mfd
I have used the force index for idx_CRD_FIT_DATE_STATUS but still the same result taking time.

table structure;

row 1:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`ESMD_ID`),
  KEY `idx_ESMD_SDM_ID` (`ESMD_SDM_ID`),
  KEY `idx_ESMD_ESM_ID` (`ESMD_ESM_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14006 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

row 2:

```
 PRIMARY KEY (`CRD_ID`),
  KEY `CRD_APP_ID` (`CRD_APP_ID`),
  KEY `idx_CRD_CMM_ID` (`CRD_CMM_ID`),
  KEY `idx_CRD_SDM_ID` (`CRD_SDM_ID`),
  KEY `idx_CRD_ZM_ID` (`CRD_ZM_ID`),
  KEY `idx_CRD_REGN_NUMBER` (`CRD_REGN_NUMBER`),
  KEY `idx_CRD_MOBILE_NUMBER` (`CRD_MOBILE_NUMBER`),
  KEY `idx_CRD_VARIFICATION_STATUS` (`CRD_VARIFICATION_STATUS`),
  KEY `idx_CRD_CHASSIS_NO` (`CRD_CHASSIS_NO`),
  KEY `idx_CRD_REGN_NUMBER_CRD_ID` (`CRD_REGN_NUMBER`,`CRD_ID`),
  KEY `CRD_FITMENT_DATE` (`CRD_FITMENT_DATE`),
  KEY `idx_crd_sdm_id_verfication_status` (`CRD_SDM_ID`,`CRD_VARIFICATION_STATUS`),
  KEY `idx_CRD_IS_REPLACEMENT` (`CRD_IS_REPLACEMENT`)
```

row 3:

```
 PRIMARY KEY (`MFD_ID`),
  KEY `MFD_STATUS` (`MFD_STATUS`,`MFD_CRD_ID`,`MFD_FITMENT_DATE`),
  KEY `idx_MFD_CRD_ID` (`MFD_CRD_ID`),
  KEY `idx_combo` (`MFD_FITMENT_DATE`,`MFD_CRD_ID`,`MFD_STATUS`),
  KEY `idx_new` (`MFD_STATUS`,`MFD_FITMENT_DATE`,`MFD_CRD_ID`),
  KEY `MFD_FITMENT_DATE` (`MFD_FITMENT_DATE`),
  KEY `idx_CRD_FIT_DATE_STATUS` (`MFD_CRD_ID`,`MFD_FITMENT_DATE`,`MFD_STATUS`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2421779 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The above index all based on cardinality

njdnsfkjndkjfbndksjbfkjdbsjkfbkjsdbfkjbdskjfbsdkjbfkjdsbjkfbkjsdbfkj

Comment: Whenever you ask about SQL query optimization, **show the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning.

Comment: mysql version 5.6.45

Comment: @AndyLester kindly check

Comment: 5.6.45 is ancient..but if that's what you have consider changing comma joins to explicit joins and what exactly is the problem you think you have and how big are the tables you access?

Comment: it's taking time

Comment: table size for row 3 is 580MB

Comment: row 2 : 1.12 GB

Comment: row 1 : 2.16 MB

Comment: What is the datatype of `MFD_FITMENT_DATE`?  Please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see other details.

Comment: There seem to be several unnecessary indexes.  When you have `INDEX(a,b)`, the shorter `INDEX(a)` is usually a waste, and sometimes gets in the way of optimization.

Comment: If the Accepted answer is not fast enough, we can discuss [_Summary Tables_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

Comment: @rick James if any suggestions are there please share

Comment: @MeritonIssac - referring to Summary Tables?  Let me know when you have studied my blog.  Then tell me some of the metrics of the table -- size, number of groupings to break it into, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop using "old style joins".  This style has not been current for over 30 years and is getting in your way.  If I re-write your query to use modern joins it looks like this:

```
SELECT  
  date(mfd.MFD_FITMENT_DATE) as MFD_FITMENT_DATE, 
  count(*) cnt_fitment 
FROM MMHSRP_FITMENT_DATE mfd
JOIN CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_DETAILS crd ON mfd.MFD_CRD_ID = crd.CRD_ID
JOIN EMBOSSING_STATION_MAPPING_DETAILS esmd ON esmd.ESMD_SDM_ID = crd.CRD_SDM_ID 
WHERE 
      esmd.ESMD_ESM_ID = '9'
  AND mfd.MFD_STATUS = '0' 
  AND mfd.MFD_FITMENT_DATE >= '2022-10-07' 
  AND mfd.MFD_FITMENT_DATE <= '2022-12-06' 
  AND crd.CRD_VARIFICATION_STATUS IN (1, 2, 4) 
GROUP BY mfd.MFD_FITMENT_DATE 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= '5000'
```

now we can see two of the filters are on linked tables -- we can move those filters to join statements (something you can't do with old style joins) like this:

```
SELECT  
  date(mfd.MFD_FITMENT_DATE) as MFD_FITMENT_DATE, 
  count(*) cnt_fitment 
FROM MMHSRP_FITMENT_DATE mfd
JOIN CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_DETAILS crd ON mfd.MFD_CRD_ID = crd.CRD_ID
                                      AND crd.CRD_VARIFICATION_STATUS IN (1, 2, 4) 
JOIN EMBOSSING_STATION_MAPPING_DETAILS esmd ON esmd.ESMD_SDM_ID = crd.CRD_SDM_ID 
                                           and esmd.ESMD_ESM_ID = '9'
WHERE mfd.MFD_STATUS = '0' 
  AND mfd.MFD_FITMENT_DATE >= '2022-10-07' 
  AND mfd.MFD_FITMENT_DATE <= '2022-12-06' 
GROUP BY mfd.MFD_FITMENT_DATE 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= '5000'
```

This should be faster.

More talk about old style joins from stackoverflow's own Arron Bernard https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

---

Sub-query version as in the comments:

```
SELECT  
  date(mfd.MFD_FITMENT_DATE) as MFD_FITMENT_DATE, 
  count(*) cnt_fitment 
FROM (
   SELECT MFD_FITMENT_DATE, MFD_CRD_ID, MFD_STATUS 
   FROM MMHSRP_FITMENT_DATE mfd
   WHERE mfd.MFD_FITMENT_DATE >= '2022-10-07' 
     AND mfd.MFD_FITMENT_DATE <= '2022-12-06' 
) AS mfd 
JOIN CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_DETAILS crd ON mfd.MFD_CRD_ID = crd.CRD_ID
                                      AND crd.CRD_VARIFICATION_STATUS IN (1, 2, 4) 
JOIN EMBOSSING_STATION_MAPPING_DETAILS esmd ON esmd.ESMD_SDM_ID = crd.CRD_SDM_ID 
                                           and esmd.ESMD_ESM_ID = '9'
WHERE mfd.MFD_STATUS = '0' 
GROUP BY mfd.MFD_FITMENT_DATE 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= '5000'
```

Comment: let me check and thanks for the info

Comment: can we able to do anything for row 3 , I have used the correct index format still it is not taking that index may I know the reason for that ? @Hogan

Comment: and the suggested join is working nice .. thanks for that

Comment: I don't know what you mean by row 3?

Comment: @MeritonIssac -- I looked again and realized I had a typo -- please use the code as it is now

Comment: Row 3 means for table mfd --> MMHSRP_FITMENT_DATE ..@Hogan

Comment: are you asking why it can't use the MFD_FITMENT_DATE index on that table?  That is because you are also filtering on MFD_STATUS -- which is not in the DATE index. @MeritonIssac

Comment: yes, can we do anything about that?

Comment: make an index that include both the date and the status -- or maybe do a sub-query -- I'll show you the subquery version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248388/discussion-between-meriton-issac-and-hogan).

Comment: @MeritonIssac Basically you need an index where all column are combined that are in the ON clause and WHERE.  You can FORCE indexes to be used, at developing stage you can make more combinations on indexes and chekc if they are better see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html  also it would be best to remove all indexes as they make everything slower and single column indexes woill not be used in multip column WHERE clauses

Comment: Plus   indexes:    mfd:  `INDEX(MFD_STATUS, MFD_FITMENT_DATE, MFD_CRD_ID)` and 
    esmd:  `INDEX(ESMD_ESM_ID, ESMD_SDM_ID)`

Comment: i have used that

Comment: @MeritonIssac -- you are going to have beter luck on this site if you don't change the question for one question but instead make a new question when you have new issues.  This will get you better engagement and you will get more (hopefully helpful) answers.